# Possible to get Flex to use custom ArrayCollection for remote object from server?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, collections, flex4, blazeds

I am thinking of writing a subclass of ArrayCollection, similar to ClearToolkit's that can be smart about managing my remote objects when coming back from BlazeDS.

I am wondering if it is possible to get Flex to put my collection of objects in my own custom collection instead of defaulting to ArrayCollection?  If not, I'll need to pull everything out of the collection it comes in in order to populate my own.  Not a huge deal, but its something I'd like to avoid if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible.  In fact, that's how we create managed or paginated collections in [dpHibernate](http://code.google.com/p/dphibernate/).

There's a blog post [here](http://martypitt.wordpress.com/2010/01/18/implementing-paged-collections-in-dphibernate/) which talks about how this works.

Comment: I think that HDave does not want to convert manually the arraycollection to another type (like you are doing in manageArrayCollection method), he wants to modify the default Flex deserialization.

Comment: Cornel -- you are correct.  Will try your approach and report back.

Answer (score 2):

On the server side, BlazeDS is wrapping the Java collections to flex.messaging.io.ArrayCollection objects and after that is serializing this class. On the Flex side, the class mx.collections.ArrayCollection is registered with the class flex.messaging.io.ArrayCollection.

In your Flex application, you may try to register your own class like that: registerClassAlias("somepackage.YourArrayCollection", ArrayCollection) and see if it works. YourArrayCollection should expose a get/set pair for the source object, like the original ArrayCollection class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that's what you mean, but you can always type cast in AS3 using the `as` keyword.